# White space on top of youtube video embedded on UIWebview

Tags: html, ios, swift, youtube

I am embedding youtube videos in my iOS app and have tried several things to get rid of a stubborn white space that shows on top and left of the video as shown below.

[image]

This is the line that is relevant:

```
        webView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(webView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(webView.frame.height)\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(selectedVideo.videoId)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
```

It looks like the actual video is placed a little to the right and down in relation to the WebView. I tried adding the line below to the HTML link and still doesn't work.

```
{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

My main suggestion is to load up the page in your simulator, then run Safari on your mac (with "Show Develop menu in menu bar" enabled in Advanced Preferences). Use the Develop menu to navigate to your embedded web view (I love that this works!). This will open up a web inspector console, in which you can play with some of the values or at least see what is really going on (is it body margin? etc.)